# Snowflake Sink connector: Connect Confluent and Snowflake Across Different Clouds and Regions

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-cloud

I want to connect my Confluent Cloud with Snowflake using Snowflake Sink connector. While I managed to do that when both Confluent cluster and Snowflake account are in the same provider and same region, I face problems when Confluent is in GCP (us-west4) and Snowflake is in AWS (eu-north-1) for example. The message I get during the setup procedure is:

> Please make sure the cloud region is supported by Snowflake and Kafka cluster and Snowflake database are in the same region.

According to Confluent [tutorial](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/cc-snowflake-sink.html#quick-start):

> The data system the sink connector is connecting to should be in the same region as your Confluent Cloud cluster. If you use a different region or cloud platform, be aware that you may incur additional data transfer charges.

But it doesn’t let me implement this.

When using the same provider and region, the flow was working correctly.

Since I don't have paid for extra support in Confluent, the support isn't available.

Did anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: It may just be a typo in your question but did you mean the AWS eu-north-1 region, rather than the eu-north region that you put?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @NickW, it was a typo.

Comment: My reading of the tutorial link you posted is that this is only possible with the help of Confluent: "Contact your Confluent account team or Confluent Support if you need to use Confluent Cloud and connect to a data system that is in a different region or on a different cloud platform."

Comment: Thanks for the answer @NickW. Since the plan that we currently have doesn't include Confluent support, I thought that someone else might have had the same issue and could share his/her experience. The thing is that even though we are paying for creating and using clusters in Confluent, they do not even answer in such basic questions, which is weird if you think that they are actually suggesting of contacting them.

Comment: I agree with Nick, that since it is a closed-source SaaS system, then only their staff would be aware of the restrictions and errors returned from their system... Confluent has Forums and community slack. In my experience, not many of their engineers follow Stackoverflow. There is also a "Give Us Feedback" button at the bottom of each docs page when something is incorrect

Comment: You're right @OneCricketeer . I already contacted them but haven't received any answers yet. Thought that maybe someone faced something similar before, that's why I posted it. I'll update the answer once I figure it out.

Comment: The alternative solution would be to self-host your Connect cluster, or maybe try using Terraform rather than Confluent Cloud UI to force the API call, and bypass any UI validation

Comment: That's an alternative indeed, but currently it is not in the table.
Just to let you know, the Snowflake support responded that the problem is on Confluent's side.